# Есть ли специальный термин для обозначения советского канцелярита?

Tags: стилистика

Есть ли специальный термин для обозначения советского канцелярита? Который отличается от дореволюционного обилием плеоназмов и дефисов

Пример:

"формирование высоких профессиональных, морально-психологических и духовно-нравственных качеств"
"все необходимые социально-бытовые условия для организации и обеспечения жизнедеятельности слушателей и курсантов"

Comment: сам термин "канцелярит" появился в советское время для обозначение собственно советских бюрократических и публицистических реалий, так что тут уж скорее вопрос можно ставить про есть для отдельное слово для дореволюционного канцелярита

пожалуйста, отредактируйте пост так, чтобы в нём был один вопрос, потому что сейчас у вас два совершенно разных вопроса - а это противоречит условиям валидности поста

Comment: Is Если ли... proper Russian and if so, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

It probably wouldn't be too far-fetched to use the term "суконный стиль".  This wording refers to "сукнo", a cloth used in the Soviet era (and prior to it) to cover standard desks in government institutions.

А synonym of "суконный стиль" is "казённый стиль".

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли специальный термин для обозначения советского канцелярита?

I believe it's the word *канцелярит* itself.

The term was coined by Korney Chukovsky in his 1962 book *Живой как жизнь*. The author used the pattern used in medicine to name inflammatory processes of organs (*бронхит, аппендицит* etc.) to convey the idea that it's a "disease of the language".

He did acknowledge that this kind of speech had its place in formal communication, but, in his opinion, it should not have been spilling into literature, journalism and everyday speech.

He explicitly states that it was not a Soviet innovation and provides a couple of examples from the older texts, but mentions that it started to spread into the literature in the 1930s:

> Стиль этот расцвел в литературе, начиная с середины 30-х годов. Похоже, что в настоящее время он мало-помалу увядает, но все же нам еще долго придется выкорчевывать его из наших газет и журналов, лекций, радиопередач и т. д.

<sub>Ironically, the term *канцелярит* would literally mean "inflammation of the office", while something "caused by the office" would rather be *канцеляроз*. But the term was good and caught on anyway.</sub>

> Который отличается от дореволюционного обилием плеоназмов и дефисов

I'm not sure if it differs that much in these particular aspects.

All three hyphenated constructs that you mention, by 1917 already had waist-long beards.

Pleonasms, wordiness and cliches grow out of laziness and uninventiveness. This is something you would naturally use if you optimize for character count per joule of brain activity.

If you need to fill a page of text or an hour of public speech with something bland, safe and not likely to get you fired, using this kind of bullshit bingo material is the way to go in all languages and all cultures.